# Error: User's function does not return NULL for empty chunks

Tags: lidr

I am trying to create a user-defined defined function for a `LAScatalog` object in R using the `lidR` package and no matter which function I create, if `opt_wall_to_wall` is set to `TRUE`, the code returns the following error:

```
Error: User's function does not return NULL for empty chunks. Please see the documentation of catalog_apply.
```

Here's how I am reading in my `LAScatalog`:

```r
LidRtst <- lidR::readLAScatalog(folder = "", filter = "-keep_class 2 3 4 5 8 9 26 -drop_x_below 7648119.63 -drop_x_above 7653883.38 -drop_y_below 675298.33 -drop_y_above 681872.34 -drop_overlap -drop_synthetic -drop_withheld -drop_number_of_returns 0 -drop_z_below 0")
lidR::las_check(LidRtst)
lidR::projection(LidRtst) <- rgdal::showWKT(as.character(LidRtst@proj4string))
lidR::opt_wall_to_wall(LidRtst) <- TRUE
lidR::opt_chunk_buffer(LidRtst) <- 100
lidR::opt_progress(LidRtst) <- TRUE
lidR:::catalog_laxindex(LidRtst)
future::plan(strategy = future::multisession, workers = detectCores())
lidR::set_lidr_threads(detectCores())
```

And here's a test to see what happens if I create a user-defined function with wall-to-wall set to `TRUE`

```r
test = function(cluster) {
  las = readLAS(cluster)

  if(is.empty(las)){
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    return(list(0))
  }
}

opt_output_files(LidRtst) <- paste0(tempdir(), "/file_{ID}")
ret = catalog_apply(LidRtst, test)
#> Error: User's function does not return NULL for empty chunks. Please see the documentation of catalog_apply.
```

Now if I set wall to wall to `FALSE`

```r
lidR::opt_wall_to_wall(LidRtst) <- FALSE
ret = catalog_apply(LidRtst, test)
head(ret)
```

It works! So how do I get a user-defined function in lidR to work wall-to-wall?

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example like [this one](https://pastebin.com/tW7BuwT1) (including data). I get `Error : Trying to write an object of class list but this type is not supported.` which is the expected error here. With `opt_output_files() = ""` it works because your function `test` is correct.